# [ltp][android][linux]compile ltp for android: fatal error: linux/time_types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I'm compiling an executable binary of ltp for android, but occur error:

```
make -C "lib" \
    -f "/tmp/ltp-android/lib/Makefile" all
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/ltp-android/lib'
In file included from tst_clocks.c:10:0:
../include/tst_timer.h:15:30: fatal error: linux/time_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/time_types.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [tst_clocks.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ltp-android/lib'
make: *** [lib-all] Error 2
```

os: centos Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64
ltp repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/ltp/+/refs/heads/android13-release

**my steps:**
execute command from repo INSTALL file:
Fedora / CentOS / RHEL
# yum install gcc git make pkgconf autoconf automake bison flex m4 kernel-headers glibc-headers

```
$: yum install gcc git make pkgconf autoconf automake bison flex m4 kernel-headers glibc-headers
$: cd ltp
$: make autotools
$: ./configure
$: make
```

occur error:

```
make -C "lib" \
    -f "/tmp/ltp-android/lib/Makefile" all
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/ltp-android/lib'
In file included from tst_clocks.c:10:0:
../include/tst_timer.h:15:30: fatal error: linux/time_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/time_types.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [tst_clocks.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ltp-android/lib'
make: *** [lib-all] Error 2
```

so what should I do to compile successfully?

I tried using a higher kernel version of ubuntu... same error!

I tried to download the [time_types.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/include/uapi/linux/time_types.h) file to /usr/include/linux, and other errors occurred.

so what should I do to compile successfully?